# Is it possible to put rgba background for option in select?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to change the default background white color of the option inside the select property, but with no success. I tried to put to my select property an rgba color but it just won't accept it together with my background image(dropdown arrow) so i wrapped it with a div and gave it my background rgba color as you can see here:

```
<div class="language-dropdown">
    <label>
        <select class="language-select">
            <option class="language-option" selected>English</option>
            <option class="language-option">Italian</option>
            <option class="language-option">Russian</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

When I try to give background rgba to .language-option it just won't change anything, **but**, if I give it a regular color, for exmaple background:red;, it works.

```
.language-dropdown {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    display: inline-block;
}
.language-select {
    background: url("http://s10.postimg.org/otetjsoat/language_Arrow.png") no-repeat right;
    background-size: auto 42%;
    width: 88px;
    background-position-x: 73px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;

    padding-left: 5px;
}
.language-option {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    /*WONT WORK!!! , but "background-color:red;"  will*/
}
```

**Note: Works on Firefox, while not on Chrome!**

You can find my whole fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ronilitman/kpas0Ls9/3/)

Comment: I am on Chrome and the alpha part doesn't seem to be working as expected. It is getting treated as though the color is just white.

Comment: Works fine in firefox for me too.

Comment: Transparent white with white text, so the whole thing just looks white for me on Chrome.

Comment: @AkulVonItram I have checked it on firefox and it does work, but not on chrome. other solution?

Answer (score 2):

it works fine [with pink color, for example](http://jsfiddle.net/kpas0Ls9/6/), you just have to set a non-white transparency color.

```
.language-option {
    background-color: rgba(212, 31, 31, 0.48);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because 255, 255, 255 - it's white:) Of course you can't see anything! Here is [answer](https://jsfiddle.net/1L1o44pq)

```css
.language-dropdown {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    display: inline-block;
}

.language-select {
    background: url("http://s10.postimg.org/otetjsoat/language_Arrow.png") no-repeat right;
    background-size: auto 42%;
    width: 88px;
    background-position-x: 73px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.language-option {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="language-dropdown">
    <label>
        <select class="language-select">
            <option class="language-option" selected>English</option>
            <option class="language-option">Italian</option>
            <option class="language-option">Russian</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Strange that it works on firefox though. The color is close enough. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
.language-option {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

This code works. It's red with a 40% opacity.

You'r rgba color `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)` is white... You won't see any difference because the background is also white.

Here you can experiment with RGBa and instantly see what it does: http://www.webopacity.net/RGBA.html